# bacon.js EventStream representing polling of url at interval

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, polling, bacon.js

I want to poll a url regularly and get the results as a stream. I'm probably missing something obvious but does anyone know how to do this seemingly simple thing in bacon.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out, this will poll `/whatever` every 5 seconds and return the results as a stream of values:

```
var ajaxE = function() {
  return Bacon.fromPromise(
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/whatever",
      dataType: "JSON"
    })
  );
};

var stream = Bacon.interval(5000).flatMapLatest(ajaxE);
```

Explained here: http://nullzzz.blogspot.com/2012/12/baconjs-tutorial-part-iii-ajax-and-stuff.html (section titled "AJAX with flatMap").

Comment: The function assigned to `ajaxE` needs to have `return` in front of `Bacon.fromPromise`.